# Probability distribution for a function of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-functions

I'm very new in the Statistic Math field, so this question maybe be a bit trivial for you guys. Anyway, I'd appreciate any guidance in this matter.

I was thinking about whether is possible to find the distribution for a function $f(x_i)$, with random variable $x_i$ satisfying $-1 \lt x_i \lt 1$, and finite $i=1,2,...,N$. For instance, suppose we have

\begin{equation}
f(x_i) = \frac{x_i}{|x_{i}|^3}, 
\end{equation}

Would be possible to find analytically which distribution function the histogram for $f(x_i)$ follows, for finite N? If it's not, can I find the distribution for $N\rightarrow \infty$?

I should also say that I have tried to implement this problem numerically, here is the result I'm getting https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G4ym5Afw8F9c17prd0daqpZCUuOtr1Xv/view?usp=sharing

We clearly can see that this doesn't follow the normal distribution neither other common distributions at first sight. Also, the middle gap region is a feature attributed to the local minimum of $f(x_i)$, due to the constraint of the $x_i$ value.

Comment: What’s the distribution of $x_i$?

Comment: @paulinho In principle $x_i$ is a random variable within [-1,1] interval, so I assume it's safe to say we have a uniform distribution between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "find the distribution of."  We can generally find $P(f(x_i) \le c)$ for most functions and random variables, so in that sense yes.  But in general it will not be any named distribution like the normal distribution.  It is very rare that functions (besides linear transforms) of random variables with well-known distributions also have well-known distributions because it is often easier to just work with the original distribution of $x_i$ for computing things like the mean or variance.

Comment: Yes, I was actually referring to $P(f(x_i))$.
Indeed, it's usually easier to simply work with the original distribution of $x_i$ to compute either the mean or the variance. However, the function I'm dealing with diverges at $x_i \rightarrow 0$, and so, if we calculate the variance for instance, we obtain $\sigma^2 = E[f(x)^2] = \int dx P(x) 1/x^4 \rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: Right, it's fine for random variables to have infinite variance.  Your example also technically doesn't have a well-defined mean either because $\int_0^1 P(x) f(x)dx = \infty$ and $\int_{-1}^0 P(x) f(x)dx = -\infty.$  You can look up the Cauchy distribution for another example of a distribution that doesn't have a well-defined mean.

Comment: Actually if we compute the integral $\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} dx P(x) f(x) + \int_{\epsilon}^{1} dx P(x) f(x)  $ and take the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ limit, we obtain mean equals to zero. You can also take a look at the link I posted above, you will realize that mean approaches to zero.

Anyhow, back to my original question would you know how can I obtain $P(f(x_i))$?
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it has a Cauchy principal value, but the problem is if you split it up like $\int_{-1}^{-\varepsilon} dx P(x)f(x) + \int_{2 \varepsilon}^1 dx P(x)f(x)$ and send $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ you get a different result.  This means things like change of variables might not work, so it's typically just said that the mean is undefined.  

By $P(f(x_i))$, do you mean the pdf of $f(x_i)$?

Comment: Yeap, it does make sense. 
I was actually interested in the pdf. I'll describe my problem physically. Maybe it will help make you understand what I'm asking. 

Assume we have one electron moving randomly along the line segment [-1,1]. To be able to model what we see on the experiment, I'm trying to compute $P(f(x_i))$ of $x/|x|^3$ (Coulomb law). The idea is to compare the average value we measure and the standard deviation with the ones predicted by statistics.

Comment: Oh, okay, so to get the pdf all you do is take $\frac{d}{dc} P(f(x_i) \le c)$.  You'll still end up with the same problems of an undefined mean and infinite variance, though.  The reason for that is that the electrons are actually moving around in $3$D space, so the probability they stay along a single line is $0$.  If you switch to integrating over $[-1,1]^3$ then everything should work out.

Comment: Thank you again! 
Actually I'm doing using the interval $[-1,1]^3$. I've just talked about the 1D case to avoid a vectorial analyzes here. Anyway, would you give me any reference on how I can calculate $P(f(x_i))$? It seems I need first calculate it in order to take the derivative with respect to $c$ you mention, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109559/discussion-between-user6247850-and-denis).